# A control type was not specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, windowsformshost

I am creating a web application in visual studio 2013 and have created a windows control using TX TextControl. This control is to be used in the web application.(http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/support/documentation/dotnet/n_browser_based.tutorial_start.htm) I have followed their example alright but the control gives the error: "A control type was not specified or the specified type could not be found".  In the web page when I pasted the sample code:

```
    <object
            classid="http:BrowserBin/BrowserApplication.dll#BrowserApplication.BrowserAppControl"
            id="BrowserApp"
            name="BrowserApp"
            width="100%"
            height="700">
    </object>
```

HTML5 complained that it does not support "classid" and looking around I changed that to data, but it cannot still work and gives the above error.

Below is the code in the BrowserAppControl:

```
    public BrowserAppControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ViewerTextControl.CreateControl();
    }

    public void LoadDocument(string sHTMLDoc)
    {
        this.ViewerTextControl.Load(sHTMLDoc, TXTextControl.StringStreamType.HTMLFormat);
    }
```

I need assistance, PLEASE.

Comment: Please post the code that you've written, so we can see what is wrong and help you.

Comment: <object
                data="http:BrowserBin/BrowserApplication.dll#BrowserApplication.BrowserAppControl"
                id="BrowserApp"
                name="BrowserApp"
                width="1000"
                height="700">
            </object>

Comment: That is the code which is in the web page

Comment: Edit your post to include it, please. No one can read it easily like that. Also, can you include the code for the actual control, please?

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<object classid="BrowserBin/BrowserApplication.dll#BrowserApplication.BrowserAppContro‌​l" id="BrowserApp" name="BrowserApp" width="1000" height="700"></object>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response, but like I said earlier on, HTML5 complains that "classid" is not a valid HTML5 attribute.  The windows control library itself contains no code as such. One line under Initialize components and a method.  I am pasting it below:         public BrowserAppControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ViewerTextControl.CreateControl();
        }

        public void LoadDocument(string sHTMLDoc)
        {
            this.ViewerTextControl.Load(sHTMLDoc, TXTextControl.StringStreamType.HTMLFormat);
        }